# How to calculate the size of copper strip with high current and high frequency?

Tags: rf, high-current, skin-effect

We can easily find the recommended cross-sectional area of copper wire when the current is DC.

But when the frequency is high, e.g., 13.56MHz, how could we calculate a suitable size of copper strip to carry this current? Under this frequency, skin effect impacts a lot. The resistance will be dozens of times that of DC. This means that the heat generated also increases significantly.

Is there any software where I can calculate or simulate this circumstance?

Or are there any books on this?

(extra info from comments) The skin depth of copper at 13.56MHz is about 20um. I learned from the Internet that the safe current of 1 mm2 copper wire is about 4-5 Amps (DC). If the same cross-sectional area is used, a 25mm wide copper strip is required. It's a really wide strip of copper. Considering the simplest calculations, a current of 80 amperes would require a copper strip width of half a meter. This width is not acceptable. (/extra info from comments)

Comment: https://www.chemandy.com/calculators/round-wire-ac-resistance-calculator.htm

Comment: Also bear in mind that the recommended cross-sectional area of copper conductors (wires or traces or whatever) are very much rules of thumb, based on all manners of assumptions, the most important ones being ambient temperature and the thermal properties of the material around the conductor (circuit board tracks can take less current than a wire suspended in a liquid, for instance), but also what is considered a OK power loss (might be based on power, might be based on allowed overtemperature)

Comment: It would show that you've done your homework if you quoted the skin depth of copper at 13.56 MHz in your question. Then you would have an idea of what thickness would be needed for 'dozens of times' AC resistance compared to DC. At RF, we normally think in terms of surface area (or rather width) of conductors, rather than cross-sectional area.

Comment: @Andyaka Thanks! A good online tool.

Comment: @MrGerber Thanks！ It is necessary to take what you said into consideration when calculating the size of copper wire. I only want to talk about the simplest situation where bare copper wires or strips are in air. Given a hypothetical temperature, how to calculate current?

Comment: @Neil_UK Thanks! I think what you said is right. However, when the RF current is high, for example, 80Amps, then the heat generated is also massive. To increase heat dissipation, I think we still need copper strips with a thickness.  I know how to calculate the skin depth before asking the question.  The calculated width is just too wide considering the skin effect. Since the current carry capacity is mainly determined by temperature, can we add the value of the current-carrying capacity of the cross-sectional area when the frequency is high?

Comment: @Mingan You may know how to calculate skin depth, but putting in your question demonstrates your effort, and allows us to pitch answers at the right level. No, the cross sectional area below the skin depth has no current carrying capacity, consider it as electrical insulator. But it is thermal conductor, which can help to control the temperature. Maybe temperature is the limiting factor, maybe resistance/Q. When I worked in MRI, we built antennae, in the MHz / 10s of MHz region, from 22 mm copper plumbing pipe, for the surface area and low resistance.

Comment: @Neil_UK Thanks for your reply. The skin depth of copper at 13.56MHz is about 20um. I learned from the Internet that the safe current of 1 mm2 copper wire is about 4-5 Amps (DC). If the same cross-sectional area is used, a 25mm wide copper strip is required. It's a really wide strip of copper. Considering the simplest calculations, a current of 80 amperes would require a copper strip width of half a meter. This width is not acceptable. There must be something else I haven't noticed.

Comment: Beware using the plane skin depth formula alone, as a round wire *in a transmission line* will not have uniform current density around the circumference. Likewise, microstrip or stripline will have more current towards the edges, though nonzero in the middle, still giving some advantage with width. But width is limited by dielectric height and characteristic impedance.

Comment: Note that if you have 5A at 13.56MHz, at 50 ohms, that's 250V and 1250VA -- this is *not* a small circuit! If you are working with impedances much too low......don't! You have all the impedance in the world, transmission lines of 50-150 ohms are perfectly reasonable, inductors have high Q, C0G capacitors are still practically ideal,  and in the narrow ISM band, reactive matching networks are cheap and effective -- no need to make a narrow bandpass filter in the ladder type with unrealistic resonator impedances, for example.

Comment: @TimWilliams Thanks. I am not sure if I should consider characteristic impedance since I am not designing PCB layout or routing. In fact, I try to design a RF match circuit with high power. The current flowing through the inductor and capacitor will be large. That is why I want to ask how to calculate the size. But maybe I can only reach my goal by experiments.

Answer (score 1):

> I learned from the Internet that the safe current of 1 mm2 copper wire is about 4-5 Amps (DC).

Well there's your problem then.

4 to 5 A/mm<sup>2</sup> is a rating, and a very conservative one at that. It makes all sorts of assumptions about the thermal environment and cooling. That sort of rating would be applicable for the copper in the windings of a small transformer (lots of heat, little cooling). You could use a 10 A rating for multiple plastic insulated wires run in a conduit.

When you get to control the thermal environment, it's only temperature that limits what current copper can carry. That means balancing the heat produced by the current with the heat lost to ambient.

What temperature is the conductor permitted to reach? Is there plastic insulation on it limiting it to maybe less than 100 C, or is it bare metal and can reach several hundred C without damaging its environment? The hotter it can get, the more heat will be lost per unit area, and the smaller conductor you can use.

Unfortunately, calculating the rate of heat loss from a conductor is a complicated affair, involving serious fluid dynamics. You should though be able to find tables online that will give you estimates for flat plate heatsinks that will give you a ballpark to work in.

Frankly, the best way for an amateur to do it is make a test conductor, heat it with a test current, and measure it in situ. Compute the resistance at RF for your test conductor taking skin depth into account, and multiply by your intended current squared to get the power you're going to dissipate. Now heat it with the same power, from RF if you have it available, otherwise DC or mains frequency (making the appropriate adjustments for lower resistance) and see how hot it gets. You could use a low power to simply estimate a Watts/C, which will be fairly linear for small temperature rises, but will be non-linear as the cooling air becomes turbulent or IR radiation becomes more significant.

Answer (score 0):

There are formulas and calculators that can estimate the skin depth. So you have an "effective" cross-section that should give you significantly more accurate results than assuming DC.

A free software that can estimate skin depth would be the [Saturn PCB Toolkit](https://saturnpcb.com/saturn-pcb-toolkit/), for example.

You can calculate the skin-depth yourself with the following formula:

[image: formula]

[image: formula]: skin depth

[image: formula]: resistivity

[image: formula]: frequency

[image: formula]: permeability

See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skin_effect

Comment: Thanks. Skin depth is really easy for us to find a method to calculate. The problem is how to calculate the size of copper strip.